# How to configure ripple emulator

Tags: cordova, ripple

Is it possible to use/configure ripple emulator to test a phonegap application that uses the emailcomposer plugin to send emails?

Comment: The only solution I found is to deploy my project on android studio and use the genymotion emulator

Answer (score 0):

Ripple doesn't support third party plugins directly. Ripple needs to emulate the functionality on browser based on the device selection etc and this emulation is available only for the core plugins as of now. You could mock the response you want when the Ripple displays the response screen and see if the app behavior is as expected.